# how to add multiple css classes to a html element usin javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add multiple classes to an html element

I know the following code is possible.

```
$("ul#List").find("li.template")
            .removeClass("template")
            .addClass("entry")
```

But i want to know if the following code is also possible.?

```
$("ul#List").find("li.template")
            .removeClass("template")
            .addClass("entry1")
                    .addClass("entry2")
```

Comment: Yes, that code will work. Although, as other have pointed out, you can do it with a single call to `addClass`, separating the classes by a space

Comment: Would it not have been quicker to try it out than to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add multiple classes separated by a space:

```
.addClass("entry1 entry2")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("ul#List").find("li.template")
            .removeClass("template")
            .addClass("entry1 entry2")
```

**Edit:**
Take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/nHs9W/

Both of the below snippets work

`.addClass("entry1 entry2");`

`.addClass("entry1").addClass("entry2");`

Comment: It's hard to tell. While it's obvious to me what's changed, @Eric, please give explanations in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

-1 for not reading the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)!

But anyway, from that page,

> .addClass( className )
>   className: One or more class names to be added to the class attribute of each matched element.

The most important part being **one or more**

Comment: I apologise, but I never set out to be rude. This answer gives a solution to your problem, and a comment on the side about not reading the most obvious source of information, and wasting our time on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: It's not a problem Saurabh :-)